# field wont show in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

i'm working with jasper reports and im trying to add a field. My jasper report is horizontal,(name(Label): value)  it doesn't show the newly created row. i've tried increasing the band height but to no avail.

```
<elementGroup>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="186" y="20" width="200" height="20" positionType="Float"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{journalTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="72" y="20" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Title]]></text>
        </staticText>
        </elementGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

try to transform your label from static text to text field, set option "PrintWhenDetailOverflows" and "StretchWithOverflow"

that should do it (other approach: resize your static text, so that the text fits in)

Answer (score 1):

try to set max height of band and set also static text height. You can also try with static text font and font size.you must check your text in particular band.